# Accidentaly hit esc during a do-release-upgrade?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, apt, 12.04, updates

While doing a `do-release-upgrade` (from 11.10 to 12.04), I  accidentally hit `esc` and noticed that this interrupted the download of the file being donwloaded at the time and then skipping to the next file. One of those files is coreutils, the other is lbssl1.0.0.

Will `do-release-upgrade` or `apt-get` reattempt a download of those files before attempting the upgrade?

I presume the install script and software is robust enough to note the dependencies and to reattempt download of those files? The process is still ongoing as I type this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll be fine other than I would rerun apt-get on the machine before rebooting. I've accidentally borked a apt-get session that just picked where it left off.

Comment: Yeah I am going to agree and say you are going to be okay, apt-get is pretty resilient